# Can a partition table be edited from a LiveUSB of another architecture?

Tags: partitioning, 64-bit, 32-bit, gparted

My purpose is to re-partition a dual-boot machine (running Ubuntu 13.04 / Windows 7), i.e. the current table is as follows:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|           |      extended partition        |            |
|  windows  |--------------------------------|  recovery  |
|  (NTFS)   |   swap   |     filesystem      |   (NTFS)   |
|           |  (swap)  |       (ext4)        |            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

and I want to create an additional ext4 partition under the extended partition, and mount those (the one I created and the 'filesystem' partition) to root and home (`/` and `/home`), such as the new layout will be:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
|           |      extended partition        |            |
|  windows  |--------------------------------|  recovery  |
|  (NTFS)   |   swap   |   root   |   home   |   (NTFS)   |
|           |  (swap)  |  (ext4)  |  (ext4)  |            |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

As the installations on the system and on my Live USB differ in architecture, I want to know:

**Is it safe to use a 64bit GParted from a Live USB for partitioning a 32bit installation?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Partitions and filesystems are architecture independent

GParted doesn't want/need to know what's the [opcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opcode) of binaries executable files a partition holds when you resize it.

Answer (score 2):

absolutely.

the only thing that will matter is whether your system can support the 64bit live cd (i.e. you have a multi-core processor)

Once the software loads you can change edit the partition tables of any storage device you have with Gparted

Comment: yes, it's an intel i5 quad core, so it'll manage that. thanks for the response!

Comment: 64-bit has nothing to do with multithreading. I think you meant multi-core.

Comment: you are right, of course. fixed.

Answer (score 0):

yeah you can use GParted from live USB, no matter which architecture. It doesnot matter as long as you are not going to install the system.

it shall go well with the live USB.

Comment: this is extraneous, please remove your answer as it duplicates other answers already posted.