# Format USB drive that is formatted as FAT32, into EXT4 from Windows 11/WSL

Tags: usb, windows-subsystem-for-linux, disk-formatting

I have a USB stick that is formatted as FAT32. I want to format it as EXT4 but I cannot do that from Windows despite following [the advice](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/connecting-usb-devices-to-wsl/). As the usb stick is formatted in FAT32 I can't see it in WSL, otherwise I would format it there.

Any other ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You can boot and run Ubuntu 'live' from another USB pendrive, and it will be able to see and format your FAT32 pendrive (create a new partition table with the file systems that you want). [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) can help you make an Ubuntu live system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a partition table be edited from a LiveUSB of another architecture?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304515/can-a-partition-table-be-edited-from-a-liveusb-of-another-architecture)